# How do I return values from a Perl method in a Vim script?

Tags: perl, vim

I'm writing a Vim script.  I have a function that uses embedded Perl.  How do I return values from my Perl code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to escape any single quotes in the value you are trying to return, and then use `VIM::DoCommand("return '$data'")`.

For example:

```
function PhoneHome()
    perl << EOF
        use IO::Socket;
        my $mothership = IO::Socket->INET->connect()
        my $data = <$mothership>;
        $data =~ s|'|''|g; # escape '
        VIM::DoCommand("return '$data'")
    EOF
endfunction
```

Also see `:help perl` and `:help perl-DoCommand`.  But for the most part this is not really documented.